# Is c[num] the same as writing c.num

Tags: javascript, while-loop, notation

I'm practicig in writing some code. In the solution to the exercise I found this line of code (see below), but I can't figure out what does `c[num]` represent and  how it works. Is the solution maybe using brackets notation instead of dot notation?

This would mean that `c[num]` is the same as saying `c.num`. Or am I on a completely wrong track?

Line of code:

```
while(num != 1 && c[num] !== true)
```

Thank you!

PS. Full solution is here: https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-conditional-statements-and-loops-exercise-8.php

Comment: Square brackets [] represents Array in JavaScript. c[num] means value from c array at index num. c = ['a','b','c','d']; num=2; x = c[num]; then x will be 'c'

Answer (score 2):

`c.num` is equivalent to `c["num"]`, not `c[num]`. `c[num]` provides a way to dynamically look up an attribute based on the value stored in a variable, so it would only be equivalent to `c.num` if `num`'s value was `"num"`. Given `num` is clearly supposed to be an integer, that's not the case.